# Combining two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having this two arrays in Python:

```
a = [ ['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3] ]
b = [ ['a',10], ['b',20], ['c',30], ['d',40] ]
```

Is it possible to combine them into a single array like this?

```
output = [ ['a',1,10], ['b',2,20], ['b',3,30], ['c',0,40] ]
```

Since 'c' doesn't exist in the first array, first integer should be 0.

Thank you.

Comment: Only the _last_ values are missing? Not, for example, from the beginning or middle of the list?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, it can be from any place.

Comment: @AndrejKesely the answer you deleted was right. Thank you!!

Comment: @FilipeYaBaPolido No, it wasn't. There's missing `['b', 2, 20]` value...

Comment: @AndrejKesely that's odd, might have missed it, let me check here again against my original array.

Comment: @AndrejKesely your code was correct, it was my mistake copy-pasting the array here at S.O. I've edited the post to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @FilipeYaBaPolido Ok, I've undeleted my answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, if missing values can be at any place, you cannot use `zip` or `zip_longest`. Here I use dicts for joining values:

```
a = [ ['a',1],  ['b',2],  ['c',3]            ]
b = [ ['a',10], ['b',20], ['c',30], ['d',40] ]

d1, d2 = dict(a), dict(b)

d = {k: [d1.get(k, 0), d2.get(k, 0)] for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys()}

print( sorted([k, *v] for k, v in d.items()) )  # use custom key= to sort them to right order (or don't use sort if you don't need it)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 1, 10], ['b', 2, 20], ['c', 3, 30], ['d', 0, 40]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that picking a dictionary for your datatype would make more sense than lists, but if you need to use lists, this is an approach:

- the lists in the original lists, are really just tuples, matching key to value; a dictionary would make more sense here
- you want one list in the result for each key in the original lists
- the lists in the result list, are really just 3-tuples, matching key to first and second value
- you want the value from the first list for each key (or 0 if none) as the first value
- you want the value from the first list for each key (or 0 if none) as the second value

```
da = {l[0]: l[1] for l in a}
db = {l[0]: l[1] for l in b}

result = [
    [k, da[k] if k in da else 0, db[k] if k in db else 0]
    for k in sorted(set(list(da.keys()) + list(db.keys())))
]

print(result)
```

Note that the `sorted()` is in there to preserve order. If alphabetical order isn't guaranteed, you can just combine the keys and dedupe using something like this:

```
def dedupe(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
```